# Make simple index

Tags: oracle

I need to make and index for this code so it will be efficient and fast

```
SELECT  * FROM Purchases  WHERE totalPrice >  59 AND spDateID =2
```

The solution I made was this:

```
CREATE INDEX Purchases_index ON Purchases(totalPrice , spDateID)
```

But now I would like to hear your opinion if this is right, or should it be done in a different way?

Comment: It depends on what other queries you will be running against the table and how many distinct, non-null values there are in each column. For this specific query, if there are a lot of totalprices above 59 this is probably the wrong way around.

Comment: Where does the APEX here?

Comment: It would be unusual to index a column like totalPrice. Assuming spDateID can have many values I would expect there to be an index on (spDateID) alone.

Comment: If one or both of the columns have a low cardinality it might be beneficial to use [key compression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5012.htm#BABHDBHE).